# Count words from input file

Tags: java, count, words

I'm stuck on a piece of code that will read input from a text file and then count how many times a certain word appears. Ive been given 4 classes, `TextReader`. The `TextReader` class reads an input file and a method called `readNextWord` will return the next word from the input file. `WordCount`, `WordCollecter` (the one where I'm stuck) and `DisplayWords`.

For the `WordCollector` class I have the following code:

```
public class WordCollector {

TextReader reader;
ArrayList countWord;
DisplayWords display;

public WordCollector(String word)
{
    TextReader reader = new TextReader(word);
    ArrayList<WordCount> countWord = new ArrayList<WordCount>(); 
    DisplayWords display = new DisplayWords();

}
```

I need to write a private method that reads the words from the `TextReader`, constructs the `WordCounts` and stores them in the `ArrayList` keeping a count of the total number of words read in. The constructor for `WordCollector` should call the private method, ensuring that the input file is completely read in and all the frequency counts are completed when the `WordCollector` is constructed. I cant seem to get my head around this part.

Here is an example, but this only uses one class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Collections;

public class reader
{

public void main(String name)
{
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br =null;

    String [] stringArray;
    int counLine = 0;
    int arrayLength ;
    String s="";
    String stringLine="";
    try{
        fr = new FileReader(name);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while((s = br.readLine()) != null){
            stringLine = stringLine + s;
            stringLine = stringLine + " ";/*Add space*/
            counLine ++;
        }

        stringArray = stringLine.split(" ");
        arrayLength = stringArray.length;
        System.out.println("There are "+arrayLength + " words");
        /*Duplicate String count code */
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            int c = 1 ;
            for (int j = i+1; j < arrayLength; j++) {
                if(stringArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase(stringArray[j])){
                    c++;
                    for (int j2 = j; j2 < arrayLength; j2++) {
                        stringArray[j2] = stringArray[j2+1];
                        arrayLength = arrayLength - 1;
                    }

                }//End of If block
            }//End of Inner for block
            System.out.println(stringArray[i]+" appears "+c+" times .");
        }//End of Outer for block
        System.out.println("The number of Lines is "+counLine);
        System.out.println();
        fr.close();
        br.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the assignment. You're supposed to work the problem out in an OOP fashion, but all your funtionality is in the `main` method. I think some of your other classes should have taken on some of those responsibilities. Just my opinion.

Comment: The public void main(String name) is not my code, its an example i found online and have been trying to use that as a sort of guide for my classes but i cant seem to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

You have not well defined your question. To me it looks like an assignment. AS you are new I'll provide some guide on that.

You have to use OOP (Object Oriented Programming).

I've provided full working code. Use this as a guide and modify it as per your requirement.

**Word Count**

```
package tutorial;

public class WordCount {

    private String word;
    private int count;



    public WordCount(String word, int count) {
        super();
        this.word = word;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

}
```

**Word Collector**

```
package tutorial;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WordCollector {

    private TextReader textReader;

    public WordCollector(File file) throws IOException {
        textReader = new TextReader(file);
    }

    public WordCount getWordCounts(String inputWord) {
        String[] extractWords = textReader.extractWords();
        int totalCount = 0;
        for (String word : extractWords) {
            if (inputWord.equals(word)) {
                totalCount++;

            }
        }

        return new WordCount(inputWord, totalCount);

    }

}
```

**TextReader (This uses Apache FileUtil library to read file)**

[FileUtil Docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)
    package tutorial;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class TextReader {

    private String fileString;

    public TextReader(File file) throws IOException {
        fileString = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
    }

    public String[] extractWords() {
        return fileString.split(" ");
    }

}
```

**DisplayWord**

```
package tutorial;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DisplayWord {

    private WordCollector wordCollector;

    public DisplayWord(File inputFile) throws IOException {
        wordCollector = new WordCollector(inputFile);
    }

    public void displayCountWord(String word) {
        WordCount wordCounts = wordCollector.getWordCounts(word);
        System.out.println("The word " + word + " has appeared "
                + wordCounts.getCount() + " times");
    }

}
```

**Quick Test**

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Test;

import tutorial.DisplayWord;

public class TestWordCount {

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {

        DisplayWord displayWord = new DisplayWord(new File("D://test.txt"));

        displayWord.displayCountWord("Church");
    }

}
```

**Sample text file**

```
Bond is a bad boy.Bond goes to temple EveryDay.Then bond everday goes to Church Church is a good place for people
lab lab lab
```

**Output**

```
The word Church has appeared 2 times
```

Comment: If it helped "Accept as Answer!